# Web browsers not displaying html entities

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, html, 22.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and everything has worked without problem apart from this. Chrome and Firefox are not displaying some html entities, this one for example: `&#11165;`. It just displays an empty box.

[image: Up arrow icon]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the issue installing the [`ttf-ancient-fonts`](https://dn-works.com/ufas/) package (Installed-Size: 9.216 B):

```
sudo apt install ttf-ancient-fonts
```

Answer (score 0):

Another font package that would help is the rather large `fonts-noto`. This weighs in at about 465MB, but generally resolves all of the unicode rendering issues that one might have in browsers and text editors.

It can be installed like this:

```
sudo apt install fonts-noto
```

Be sure to restart your browsers so they can load the font into memory, which is done only when the applications open. Then you should be able to [open this page](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2B9D) to test that the character is properly rendering:

[image: Screenshot of Unicode Character]